# How do you solve the problem if you use the JWT authentication method and client browser's cookies are completely blocked?

Tags: google-chrome, http, authentication, web

When using the JWT authentication method, the token is usually stored and used in session storage.

For Chrome, you can select the option "Do not use cookies completely" in Personal Information and Security.

In this case, local storage and session storage are also unavailable.

Of course, begging the user to allow cookies could be a solution, but what process should we follow to apply the method of keeping the login regardless of the user's settings?

It is only emerging in my head to the extent that I have to communicate a lot with the server, and I have a lot of thoughts.

I wonder if there is a way to consider security.

Thank you for all your advice and help.

Comment: `I wonder if there is a way to consider security` - this is why you have such options. You mean to kill that security level ? Google themselves are advising to keep the cookies ON if you want to use their services. So, an authentication cookie is not a big deal for privacy breach IMO.

Comment: @Kris That's right. Google's recommendations and precautions are written. Also, most sites did not work well when cookies were completely blocked through that function. However, I asked if there is a way to perform authentication even in this situation. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you don't have access to cookies or local storage, then your only storage is window level cache, which will go off when reloaded, I think that would be bad. Another option could be a certificate authentication, where your website can issue client certificates to users.